# Adding attachment from local filepath in sendmail

Tags: java, sendgrid

I am trying to attach a local file at path `/Users/david/Desktop/screenshot5.png` in sendgrid.

```
    Mail mail = new Mail(from, subject, to, message);

    // add an attachment
    Attachments attachments = new Attachments();
    Base64 x = new Base64();
    String encodedString = x.encodeAsString("/Users/david/Desktop/screenshot5.png");
    attachments.setContent(encodedString);
    attachments.setDisposition("attachment");
    attachments.setFilename("screenshot5.png");
    attachments.setType("image/png");

    mail.addAttachments(attachments);
```

What would be the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You added the file path.
You should add the file content instead:

```
Mail mail = new Mail(from, subject, to, message);

// add an attachment
Attachments attachments = new Attachments();
File file = new File("/Users/david/Desktop/screenshot5.png");
byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
String encodedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(fileContent);
attachments.setContent(encodedString);
attachments.setDisposition("attachment");
attachments.setFilename("screenshot5.png");
attachments.setType("image/png");

mail.addAttachments(attachments);
```

}