# Sending Email using SendGrid with java

Tags: java, spring, sendgrid

I'm new to software development and been trying to develop an application in java to send a multi content email(plain text and html file) using SendGrid but I'm only getting the HTML file. Kindly help me to fix this issue. Here is my code.

```
Email from = new Email("sebatti20@gmail.com");
String subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun";
Content content = new Content();
content.setType("text/plain");
content.setValue("This is a simple text");
content.setType("text/html");
content.setValue("This is an HTML text");
Personalization personalization = new Personalization();
Email to = new Email();
to.setEmail("sabbyelavumkal@gmail.com");
personalization.addTo(to);
Email to2 = new Email();
to2.setEmail("jojimathew.mec@gmail.com");
personalization.addTo(to2);
Email Cc = new Email();
Cc.setEmail("sebastianthomas.mec@gmail.com");
personalization.addCc(Cc);
Mail mail = new Mail();
mail.setFrom(from);
mail.setSubject(subject);
mail.addContent(content);
mail.addPersonalization(personalization);
endGrid sg = new SendGrid("SENDGRID API");
Request request = new Request();
try {
    request.setMethod(Method.POST);
    request.setEndpoint("mail/send");
    request.setBody(mail.build());
    Response response = sg.api(request);
    System.out.println(response.getStatusCode());
    System.out.println(response.getBody());
    System.out.println(response.getHeaders());
} catch (IOException ex) {
    throw ex;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You override the text content with HTML.
If you want both you should write it like this:

```
Content plainContent = new Content("text/plain", "This is a simple text");
Content htmlContent = new Content("text/html", "This is an HTML text");
mail.addContent(plainContent);
mail.addContent(htmlContent);
```

Comment: are you getting only HTML?

Comment: Sry it doesn't work for me. Is there any other possible way?

Comment: Yeah...I get only the HTML part in the mail

Comment: I tried running your code with the fix myself and I'm getting both. I see you send to Gmail, do you look in "Show original" to see the text plain?

Comment: Okay...I will check myself. Can you find me away to attach a file from the local disk and send email via SendGrid

Comment: Here is a way for adding an attachment from local file path using Sendgrid - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52127523/4419613)

Comment: @Sebastian If it worked please mark the answer as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)